# How to reload Datatable by Ajax (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm using Ajax for Crud operations in laravel 5.6 and I want to reload my table after insertion of data into the table.

This is how my table looks like without data:

[image: Empty Table]

After insertion, table looks like this:

[image: Population table]

Even after the data is added, when i search it doesn't consider the newly appended data in the table so my search result remains - no data available in the table.

The site.js

```
$(".complete-table").each(function(){
    $(this).DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            // 'copyHtml5',
            // 'excelHtml5',
            // 'csvHtml5',
            // 'pdfHtml5'
        ]
    } );
});
```

I tried a couple of things but it didn't work for me.
**The HTML for the table**

```
<table id="asset-{{ $asset_receive->asset_received_id }}" class="complete-table table toggle-circle table-hover" data-page-size="15">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Tag ID</th>
            <th> Asset Category </th>
            <th> Manufacturer</th>
            <th> Serial Number </th>
            <th> Model Number </th>
            <th> Colour</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>                                                      

  <tbody id="asset-table-{{ $asset_receive->asset_received_id }}">
  @foreach($assets->where('asset_received_id',  '=', $asset_receive->asset_received_id) as $asset)
      <tr>
          <td>{{ $asset->tag_id}}</td>
          <td>{{ $asset->asset_categories['category']}}</td>
          <td>{{ $asset->manufacturers['manufacturer']}}</td>
          <td>{{ $asset->serial_number}}</td>
          <td>{{ $asset->model_number}}</td>
          <td>{{$asset->colour}}</td>
      </tr>
  @endforeach
  </tbody>
```

Here is my Js function for the adding data into the table.

```
  $(document).on('click', 'button.submit-asset-received', function() {
    assetReceivedId = $(this).data('asset-received-id');
    assetFormId = 'form#form-assets-record-' + assetReceivedId;
    $('.error').addClass('hidden');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/addAsset',
        indexForm: assetFormId,
        indexValue: $(assetFormId + ' input[name=asset_a_category_name]').val(),
        indexManufacturer: $(assetFormId + ' select[name=a_manufacturer_id] option:selected').text(),
        data: {
            '_token': $(assetFormId + ' input[name=_token]').val(),
            'tag_id': $(assetFormId + ' input[name=tag_id]').val(),
            'asset_category_id': $(assetFormId + ' input[name=asset_a_category_id]').val(),
            'manufacturer_id': $(assetFormId + ' select[name=a_manufacturer_id] option:selected').val(),
            'serial_number': $(assetFormId + ' input[name=serial_number]').val(),
            'model_number': $(assetFormId + ' input[name=model_number]').val(),
            'colour': $(assetFormId + ' input[name=colour]').val(),
            'asset_received_id': assetReceivedId,
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if((data.errors)){
                var errors = data.errors;
                $.each(errors, function (key, value) {
                    $('input[name=' + key + ']').next('p').removeClass('hidden');
                    $('input[name=' + key + ']').next('p').text(value);
                    if(key === 'manufacturer_id'){
                        $('select[name=a_manufacturer_id]').next('p').removeClass('hidden');
                        $('select[name=a_manufacturer_id]').next('p').text(value);
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $('#asset-table-'+data.assets.asset_received_id).append("<tr>"+
                    // "<td>" + data.asset_category_id + "</td>"+
                    "<td>" + data.assets.tag_id + "</td>"+
                    "<td>" + this.indexValue + "</td>"+
                    "<td>" + this.indexManufacturer +"</td>"+
                    "<td>" + data.assets.serial_number + "</td>"+
                    "<td>" + data.assets.model_number + "</td>"+
                    "<td>" + data.assets.colour + "</td>"+
                    "</tr>");

                var aTable = $('#asset-'+data.assets.asset_received_id).parent('table').dataTable();
                aTable.ajax.reload();

                $('#unassigned').html(data.view_1);
                if(data.asset_received.qty_received != data.asset_received.qty_recorded){
                    $("form#form-assets-record-" + data.assets.asset_received_id).show();
                }else{
                    $("form#form-assets-record-" + data.assets.asset_received_id).hide();
                }
                //increase quantity recorded of this asset by taking current value and increasing by one
                var currentRecordedQuantity = parseInt($("td#qty_recorded_"+data.assets.asset_received_id).text());
                console.log(currentRecordedQuantity);
                $("td#qty_recorded_"+data.assets.asset_received_id).text(currentRecordedQuantity+1);
                $('input[name=tag_id]').val('');
                $('select[name=a_manufacturer_id]').val('');
                $('input[name=serial_number]').val('');
                $('input[name=model_number]').val('');
                $('input[name=colour]').val('');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I tried using two different ways(in the js function for adding the asset) to solve the problem but they both failed and i don't know whether i did it wrongly.

**First method**

```
var aTable = $('#asset-table-'+data.assets.asset_received_id).parent('table').dataTable();
```

aTable.ajax().reload();

**Second method**

```
var aTable = $('#asset-table-'+data.assets.asset_received_id).parent('table').dataTable();
aTable.fnDraw();
```

is there a better way of reloading the table to notice any newly added data?
Any suggestions will be welcomed, thanks in advance.

Comment: Note there are slight differences in the way `DataTable()` and `dataTable()` work

Comment: @charlietfl... what are the differences between them and how does/do they affect my code or better still, do you have a fix for my problem?

Comment: Best to review the docs regarding the differences

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for .draw()

https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()

In success of your ajax call, simply do:

```
var table = $('.complete-table').DataTable();
table.draw();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is method called

```
var table = $('.complete-table').DataTable();
table.ajax.reload();
```

Comment: How to add another data?

Answer (score 0):

Ok you first to tell your ajax request what you will receive so

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/addAsset',
    indexForm: assetFormId,
    dataType:'html',
```

now your return will be in separated blade file 
in your controller will return

```
return view('table',compact('data_that_you_fetched_form'));
```

now in your table.blade file add the html

```
 @foreach($data_that_you_fetched_form as $asset)
  <tr>
      <td>{{ $asset->tag_id}}</td>
      <td>{{ $asset->asset_categories['category']}}</td>
      <td>{{ $asset->manufacturers['manufacturer']}}</td>
      <td>{{ $asset->serial_number}}</td>
      <td>{{ $asset->model_number}}</td>
      <td>{{$asset->colour}}</td>
  </tr>
```

@endforeach

and finally add it to your table

```
success: function(data) {
   $(asset-table-'{{ $asset_receive->asset_received_id }}').html(data);
 }
```

I think that will work fine and clean and easy to modify

Comment: and if forgot you need to rebuilt  datatable in success